# C# - System.Timers synchronization issue

Tags: .net, multithreading, sockets, networking, timer

I'm currently making a Remote Administration Tool in C#, using the UDP protocol.

Becuase UDP is connectionless, I've made the clients send a Keep-Alive packet every second, and on the server side, each time a client connects, a new timer is created for the new client, with the interval of 2 seconds (if 2 seconds pass without a packet being received from the client, the client times out and is considered disconnected).

Now, the problem is, when I connect multiple users, only when the first one disconnects the server detects that. When other users continue to time out and disconnect, the server doesn't notice and it seems as if like the clients are still connected.

As for the client objects - every client has a timer parameter, which is automatically created with a constructor every time a Client object is created.

The userID variable is a class variable in the Form, that is supposed to count the amount of total connected users.

Here is the server side code:

```
        void Receive()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            bool pass = true;
            byte[] msg = new byte[1024];
            IPEndPoint Sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            EndPoint Remote = (EndPoint)Sender;
            try { server.ReceiveFrom(msg, ref Remote); }
            catch { pass = false; }
            if (pass)
            {
                Thread handle = new Thread(() => HandleInput(msg, Remote));
                handle.Start();
            }
        }
    }
    void HandleInput(byte[] msg, EndPoint Remote)
    {
        string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(msg);
        data = data.Replace("\0", "");
        if (data.Contains("Connect!"))
        {
            clients.Add(new Client(Remote, userID));
            clients[userID].timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => Timeout(sender, e, clients[userID-1]);
            clients[userID].timer.Enabled = true;
            listBox1.Items.Add(Remote.ToString());
            userID++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < clients.Count; i++)
        {
            if (EndPoint.Equals(clients[i].Remote, Remote))
            {
                clients[i].timer.Interval = 2000;
            }
        }
    }
    void Timeout(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e, Client user)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Remove(user.Remote.ToString());
        label2.Text = user.Remote.ToString() + " Disconnected";
    }
```

The client sided code isn't really important - the Keep-Alive there is just a packet being sent every second.

So, why does the server detect only the first disconnection?

I've tried changing several things with the timers, but with no luck.

Do you guys have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what if userId is always the same?

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed such a thing. Thanks a lot!